# How to store a series of data

Tags: pine-script

I am using Renko chart that can overlay the conventional Candles chart.
And Im trying to store the open value of renko when the every new brick produced.So that I can calculate renko's EMA or RSI。

I always store the same data whenever no new bricks are produced.
Here is what im trying:

```
renko_src := 0.0
if renko_src[1] != renko_top
    renko_src := renko_top
else
    renko_src := nz(renko_src[1],0)
plot(renko_src,color=color.white, linewidth=4, title="Renko")
//----------------------------


//---The_original_Renko_code 
BrickSize = 50
Brick1    =  close >
        nz(Brick1[1]) + BrickSize ? nz(Brick1[1]) + BrickSize : close <
                    nz(Brick1[1]) - BrickSize ?
                        nz(Brick1[1]) - BrickSize
                            : nz(Brick1[1])

Brick2 = Brick1 != Brick1[1] ? Brick1[1] : nz(Brick2[1])
colorer = Brick1 > Brick2 ? green:red
p1=plot(Brick1, color = colorer, linewidth= 4, title = "Renko")
p2=plot(Brick2, color = colorer, linewidth= 4, title = "Renko")
fill(p1,p2, color = purple, transp= 50)
```

I need a series that store every brick's open price that is deduplicaed

Comment: Hi, If I understand correctly how your code works, you are creating consecutive bars with the same Renko opens until a new brick is created. Then you get another stretch of bars with the Renko open of the new bar. Even if you create another parallel series with a single open value at the time a new brick is created, and then zero or `na` values until the next new brick, I don't see how you would then be able to calculate an EMA or an RSI from such a series of discontiguous values.

Comment: What I understand from your description and Luc's comment is that you want saving a real 'tick' which produced bunch of renko bricks. Is that right? If it is (and in case you capable to determine where the price was real) then it'd be easier to change implementation of EMA/RSI which will concider only those real prices that you should save in a way Luc has described above.